# Re projecting Tiff file from the Mollweide Projection to Mercator Projection using Gdal 2.2

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I'm currently looking at re-projecting a tiff file I have of population density. The file is using The Mollweide Projection.

I have come to understand that Gdal would allow me to do this. I have downloaded the software and have been through a few really good basic tutorials [Robert Simmon blog](https://medium.com/planet-stories/a-gentle-introduction-to-gdal-part-2-map-projections-gdalwarp-e05173bd710a).

I am now trying to apply the same steps to the file I have. I've typed the following command:
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3395 -r lanczos -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -co COMPRESS=LZW F:\ArcGis\Gdal\NE1_50M_SR_W\DensityMaps\Pop1Warpped.tif F:\ArcGis\Gdal\NE1_50M_SR_W\DensityMaps\Pop1Warpped_Mercator.tif

The cmd window just displays a 0, I've let it run for a couple of hours as I thought it might be a problem of file size. I was thinking that it just meant that the software was processing the file. The original file is 340mb.

I've got a feeling that my gdalwarp command might be wrong or the file size is too big. With my little knowledge of python or gdal the solution is eluding me.

Original File gdalinfo:

```
C:\Users\ttomt>gdalinfo F:\ArcGis\Gdal\NE1_50M_SR_W\DensityMaps\Pop1Warpped.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: F:\ArcGis\Gdal\NE1_50M_SR_W\DensityMaps\Pop1Warpped.tif
Size is 141988, 60942
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["World_Mollweide",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
Origin = (-17619594.547443531000000,8750529.461868489200000)
Pixel Size = (250.000000000000000,-250.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-17619594.547, 8750529.462) (  4d35'30.71"W, 83d37'50.88"N)
Lower Left  (-17619594.547,-6484970.538) (107d 3'58.73"E, 55d59' 2.97"S)
Upper Right (17877405.453, 8750529.462) ( 15d11'38.88"E, 83d37'50.88"N)
Lower Right (17877405.453,-6484970.538) (103d21'55.35"W, 55d59' 2.97"S)
Center      (  128905.453, 1132779.462) (  1d17'47.23"E,  9d10'35.76"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Run gdalinfo for the source image and add the report to your question.

Comment: When I try reducing the sizeit gives me this comment: C:\Users\ttomt>gdal_translate -r lanczos -tr 0.1 0.1  -co COMPRESS=LZW F:\ArcGis\Gdal\NE1_50M_SR_W\DensityMaps\Pop1Warpped.tif F:\ArcGis\Gdal\NE1_50M_SR_W\DensityMaps\Pop1Warpped_reduced.tif
Input file size is 141988, 60942
0ERROR 1: GTiffCreateCopy():No space for strip arrays
ERROR 1: MissingRequired:TIFF directory is missing required "StripOffsets" field
ERROR 1: MissingRequired:TIFF directory is missing required "StripOffsets" field

Comment: It could help to create a tiled tiff as output `-co TILED=YES`. If that does not help try to create an uncompressed output and compress it later.

Comment: Thanks for helping me @user30184. I tried the tiled commend. It is attempting to create even larger files. C:\Users\ttomt>gdal_translate -r lanczos -tr 0.1 0.1 -co TILED=YES F:\ArcGis\Gdal\NE1_50M_SR_W\DensityMaps\Pop1Warpped.tif F:\ArcGis\Gdal\NE1_50M_SR_W\DensityMaps\Pop1Warpped_reduced.tif
Input file size is 141988, 60942
0ERROR 3: Free disk space available is 271025307648 bytes, whereas 216325817400000000 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.

Comment: Can you point to some test data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I've downloaded the initial data from this website: http://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/GHSL/GHS_POP_GPW4_GLOBE_R2015A/GHS_POP_GPW42000_GLOBE_R2015A_54009_1k/V1-0/ . They have different levels of accuracy for their data I realised I was using the larger ones so I've started trying with the 1km accuracy. The cmd prompt is computing it right now to see what it comes up with.

Comment: With you gdal_translate command you ask GDAL to chance the original pixels size 250 m into 0.1 m. And I was meaning that can you show where to get the same or similar data for testing. Direct download link most apprecialted.

Comment: would I go about this by using - outsize 0,1 0? You'll access the direct download by clicking the zip file at this location: http://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/GHSL/GHS_POP_GPW4_GLOBE_R2015A/GHS_POP_GPW41975_GLOBE_R2015A_54009_250/V1-0/

Comment: Why do you use gdal_translate here if your aim is to change the projection? You need gdalwarp for that. Give the TILED=YES option for gdalwarp.

Comment: I'm using translate because I want to reduce the size of the original data. If I don't the gdalwarp doesn't manage to create a file. the output file is far too big apparently

Comment: In that case you either increase the pixels size with `-tr 2500 2500` or decrease the outsize `-outsize 10% 10%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the lanczos resampling makes the process to jam. Use other resampling methods, starting from nearest that is the fastest and see if the result is good enough for you. This command should run in about half an hour.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3395 -r nearest -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 input.tif output.tif
```

If you want to look the result with a GIS client like QGIS you should also create overviews with gdaladdo http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html for making the browsing faster. It is better to write external overviews with the -ro option because adding LZW compressed overviews into existing large image is very slow.

```
gdaladdo -ro output.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64 --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW LZW
```